# checking if all elements in a list satisfy a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to iterate over a list of integers returned by a function.

Problem: i want to check if any element in the list is greater than a specific value (95), then perform a statement **once**, not for every iteration, i.e. go through the list, detect a number above 95 even if there are more, then perform the statement.

I've tried but the statement keep executing as many times the condition is met

here is a code i'm trying it on

```
for path in Path(spath).iterdir():
    for n in cosine_sim(file, path):
        x = all(n)
        if x > 95:
            print("suceess...")
```

the `success...` prints multiple times

Comment: maybe use a while loop for that instead of the for loop?

Comment: You can use an `any` call as well such as `if any(x > 95 for x in my_list):`. I could give a better example but I am confused what is a list in your code. Also `all` returns a Boolean so your `if x > 95` is always false.

Comment: the function cosine_sim(file, path) returns a list (int, int, int, int...)

Comment: Your title says "all" but your description says "any" - you mean "any", right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding **Green Cloak Guy** answer, with addition of `break`

```
for path in Path(spath).iterdir():
    for n in cosine_sim(file, path):
        if all(int(x) < 95 for x in n):
            print("suceess...")
            break
    break
```

two `break` because there are two loops...

Answer (score 9):

Python has built-in functions that do roughly what you want:

- `any(iterable)` returns true if at least one element from `iterable` is truthy
- `all(iterable)` returns true if every element from `iterable` is truthy

With that in mind, the general idiom for this is to check the condition on each element of your list, and then use `all()` or `any()` on it:

```
for n in cosine_sim(file, path):
    if all(x > 95 for x in n):
        print("success...")
```

This might be a bit slower than you want, because it actually has to calculate `x > 95` for every `x`. If you're in a situation where you want to, say, make sure every number in your list `nums` is not equal to zero, or make sure that no string in `strs` is empty, you could just use `all(nums)` or `all(strs)` - since the number 0, and the empty string both evaluate as false, so you don't have to transform them into booleans first.

Comment: ...if all(x > 95 for x in n):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'...

Comment: Your data in `n` might be stored as strings instead of ints, in which case you'd need to do `int(x) > 95` instead. This type of solution can easily be tailored to any condition you need, depending on what type your data is and what the condition is that you need to check.

Comment: Note that `any` and `all` will short circuit as soon as a condition returns `True` or `False`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```py
your_list=[123,232,121,100,98]

if any(i > 95 for i in your_list):
  print("success...")
```

Comment: Simpler to do `any(i > 95 for i in your_list)`, and faster too cause it short circuits